# What is difference between 1 composite index key and seperate index key when using index query

Tags: mysql

What is difference between 1 composite index key and separate index key when using index query?

```
`users` (
 **KEY `index` (`email`,`name`)**
)

`users` (
 **KEY `email`(`email`),
 KEY `name`(`name`)**
)
```

Comment: A better example might be something like a list of countries, their type of government (democracy, monarchy, etc.) and the size of the population

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a small part of the story...

Consider the following:

```
country        continent governance              population
Afghanistan    Asia      Islamic Republic                31
Albania        Europe    Constitutional Republic          3
France         Europe    Constitutional Republic         66
India          Asia      Constitutional Republic       1210
Mauritania     Africa    Islamic Republic                 3
Spain          Europe    Consitutional Monarchy          47
United Kingdom Europe    Consitutional Monarchy          64
```

If I wanted to search for Asian countries whose governance was 'Islamic Republic' then an index on (`continent`,`governance`) would be useful.
However, if I wanted to search for countries generally whose governance was 'Islamic Republic' then I would not be able to use this index. I could use (`governance`,`continent`) or just (`governance`) however.

Answer (score 0):

The first one allows the rows to have a unique constraint imposed upon the two fields together, ie, allows following rows

```
email         name
a@b.com       user1
a@b.com       user2
b@b.com       user2
a@b.com       user1 ----> Invalid
```

While the second requires both the columns to be unique.

```
email         name
a@b.com       user1
a@b.com       user2 ----> Invalid
b@c.com       user3
d@e.com       user4
d@f.com       user4 ----> Invalid
```

Real life scenario would be identifying students in a class by their names as keys. There can be many students with same name, so naturally can't be imposed as unique. However, a composite key with name and date of birth would prove to be a good key in that case.